# JavaFX - Why system.out.println doesn't work in my application

Tags: javafx

I want to get a console output in my application debugging, but wherever I put println method console doesn't print anything. For example, I want to get "Hi" after clicking the "play" button, everything except println, will invoke normally.

```
@FXML
protected void handlePlayButton(ActionEvent event) {

    System.out.println("hi!");

    filePath = cTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getFilePath();
    index = cTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    player = new Play();
    player.player(filePath);


}
```

Comment: I doubt that it's a JavaFX issue and suggest you create a simple standard Java class with a main method which only includes a simple System.out.println. I guess that won't work either and you either have an eclipse issue (bug?) or a console output issue (redirection?).

Comment: Java Class with println in main works fine so it's must be something in javafx.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with where the stdout is pointing. Are you running it inside an IDE or might it have been redirected somewhere else in your code?

Comment: For now I'm just building it in Eclipse.